# Python 2 class with ordered properties and dict interface?

Tags: python-2.7

I have seen [How to read class attributes in the same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459531/how-to-read-class-attributes-in-the-same-order-as-declared) but answers there are for Python 3, and I'm still at loss how I could do what I want "easily".

Basically, I want a class like this:

```python
class MyClass(object):
  someprop = 1
  otherprop = ""
  thirdprop = ""
  def say_hello():
    print("hello {}".format(self.someprop))

myobj = MyClass()
myobj.newprop = "test"
```

where:

- I can add arbitrary properties outside of the class definition (which is already taken care of in the above example by inheriting from `object`)
- I would have an OrderedDict interface to the object, so I can:

  - have both "dot access" to properties (already there, `myobj.newprop = "test"`), and a dict-like access (as in `myobj["newprop"] = "test")` (get and set)
  - get a list of all properties (but not methods) in order of definition, when I call `.keys()` - so for the above example, `myobj.keys()` should return `["someprop", "otherprop", "thirdprop", "newprop"]`
  - use the object directly in `json.dumps(myobj)`, and get an ordered output (which for the above example, would be the string `{"someprop": 1, "otherprop": "", "thirdprop": "", "newprop": "test"}`)

How can this be implemented in Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a bit tricky, but managed to get it to work as I want it:

```python
from collections import OrderedDict
import json


# NOTE: class MyClass(object)/OrderedObjectDict 
# for the most part worked without to_json method,
# but when calling `json.dumps(myobj)`, it failed with:
# TypeError: <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fe2478be510> is not JSON serializable
# That is because python2.7/json/encoder.py _iterencode checks known types, e.g.
# isinstance(o, dict)
# So, we might want to somehow also inherit from a dict type - but:
# class MyClass(object, OrderedDict): fails with:
#   TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
#       Cannot create a consistent method resolution
#   order (MRO) for bases object, OrderedDict
# However, if OrderedDict is first, then object "compiles";
# ... however, this still does not help with JSON serializable - see:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable
# We can get rid of OrderedDict in MyClass(OrderedDict, object), and instead
# use to_json() in class, but we must monkeypatch as in
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/3768895#38764817:
from json import JSONEncoder
def _default(self, obj):
  return getattr(obj.__class__, "to_json", _default.default)(obj)
_default.default = JSONEncoder().default
JSONEncoder.default = _default

class OrderedObjectDict(object):
  # MUST be redefined as class property!
  __dict__ = OrderedDict()

  # __setattr__, __getattr__ handle "dot access", that is, attribute values
  # __getitem__, __setitem__ handle "dict access"
  # https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/setattr.html
  # https://www.codespeedy.com/__setitem__-and-__getitem__-in-python-with-example

  # MUST have __setattr__: if it is commented, myobj.__dict__.keys() will return empty []
  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    #print("__dict__ type: ", type(self.__dict__))
    self.__dict__[name] = value

  # MUST have __getattr__: else if it is commented, print(myobj.someprop) fails with:
  # AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'someprop'
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return self.__dict__[name]

  # MUST have __getitem__: else if it is commented, print(myobj["someprop"]) fails with:
  # TypeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
  def __getitem__(self, name):
    return self.__dict__[name]

  # MUST have __setitem__: else if it is commented, `myobj["someprop"] = 2` fails with:
  # TypeError: 'MyClass' object does not support item assignment
  def __setitem__(self, name, value):
    self.__dict__[name] = value

  def keys(self):
    return self.__dict__.keys()

  # remaining dict methods can be seen in:
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014621/a-python-class-that-acts-like-dict#23976949
  # but are not really needed for json.dumps; to handle json.dumps, we go with
  # to_json method as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/3768895#38764817

  def to_json(self):
    return self.__dict__ # or how you want it to be serialized


class MyClass(OrderedObjectDict):
  def __init__(self): # https://stackoverflow.com/a/44579432
    self.someprop = 1
    self.otherprop = ""
    self.thirdprop = ""

  def say_hello():
    print("hello {}".format(self.someprop))


myobj = MyClass()
myobj.newprop = "test"

print(myobj.keys())
print(myobj.someprop)
print(myobj["someprop"])

myobj["someprop"] = 2
print(myobj["someprop"])

print(json.dumps(myobj))

"""
output:

$ python2 test.py
['someprop', 'otherprop', 'thirdprop', 'newprop']
1
1
2
{"a": 2, "b": 3}
{"someprop": 2, "otherprop": "", "thirdprop": "", "newprop": "test"}

"""
```